# Horizontal scrolling upon button click (viewport + scrollLeft)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am pretty sure it's a very very easy question, but even after several hours of reading through Stackoverflow/Google.. still no luck.

I have a horizontal scrolling website, works great. Now i've added two buttons at the bottom of the screen (left/right).

If a visitor clicks on the 'right' button, i want the whole page to scroll to the next 'section', which is exactly $(window).width() pixels to the right.

My idea was to add so jquery that upon clicking the button ScrollLeft: $(window).width() + $(window).ScrollLeft().

Theoretically this would start with the first click scrolling rightwards exactly the width of the viewport. the 2/3/4 click it would start at the current ScrollLeft() position and once more add the viewport width.

the jquery that i use for this is the following (most likely it's somewhat bloated, jquery is not my strongsuit)

I've tried defining variables, break it down further etc. All to no avail.

```
        $(".right a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("html, body").animate({ 
        scrollLeft: $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width()
    }, "slow"); //Animates the scroll
});
        $(".left a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({ 
        scrollLeft: $(window).scrollLeft() - $(window).width() 
    }, "slow"); //Animates the scroll
});
```

-edit-

as requested here the HTML markup.

The articles inside #horz-wrap are actually scrolling.

```
 <div class="sitewrap">
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
        <section id="horz-wrap">
            <article class="post">
            <!--section here-->
            </article>
            <article class="post">
            <!--section here-->
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
    <ul class="horz-nav">
        <li class="left"><a href="#">&#60;</a></li>

        <li class="right"><a href="#">&#62;</a></li>   
    </ul>
```

--edit 2--

Upon request I just uploaded the page, live version: http://lauretf35.thirtyfive.axc.nl/laurens/test.html
Thanks!

Comment: I dont think the body,html needs to be animated, its the sections inside, can should show the html code, not the entire code, just the basic inside the body

Comment: @Lukcy Chingi, just added brief markup of the HTML. What actually is working right now is that upon clicking the buttons i can scroll 1 section to the right and back. However any further it will not go. If i create variable out of the $(window).width and $(window).scrollLeft Firebug keeps telling me the ScrollLeft variable remains 0. Hence it only once scrolls to the right, because after that the next scrollLeft position is still only $(Window).width (as apparently $(window).scrollLeft remains 0.

Comment: Are all your sections wrapped in portfolio-wrapper?, if yes, then on click apply JS code to portfolio-wapper

Comment: What do you want to scroll? One `section` at a time or one `article` at a time?

Comment: @Lucky Chingi, just applied the JS to portfolio-wrapper, not moving at all anymore then. I've put the original (Body, HTML) back, now it scrolls again, but only 1 section to the right and back to the start.

Comment: @Abhitalks I want to scroll 1 article to the right upon every click. The HTML is styled in a way that 1 article always fits in the viewport. Hence my attempt to use the actual viewport width as an input.

Comment: http://trgraglia.github.io/jquery.horizonScroll.js/demo/index.html

Comment: @LuckyChingi just put it online quickyl: http://lauretf35.thirtyfive.axc.nl/laurens/test.html

Comment: @laurens1991 I actually wanted to see the entire site with all sections to understand the layout, check the link I sent earlier, you might not have to do your own coding

Comment: @LuckyChingi, What i uploaded has several sections, if you use the buttons at the bottom you will be able to scroll to the second section, after that you will need to manually scroll to the right to see the other. Layout wise this is it, there will be content in the overlays, which so far all scrolls fine (albeit until the second section).

Comment: @laurens1991: There are a couple of ways to do this. If you do not want to change your existing markup, then one way could be to scroll the `.portfolio-wrapper` and use the `section#horz-wrap` as a holder. To keep the articles full-width, use the viewport units. See here -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y9z3sbrj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the change you need, you may still need some fix but this will help with scrolling.

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
var target = $(this.hash);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
if (target.length) {
$('table').animate({
scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
}, 1000);
return false;
}
}
});
});
```

CSS:

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, after giving the table position: absolute it all came together even with my original Jquery! only thing left to do was to fix the background image! works like a charm!